# Intersection of a family of closed Lie subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If I have a Lie group $G$, and $\{H_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a family of closed Lie subgroups with Lie algebra $\{\mathfrak{h}_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$, it's easy to see that $\bigcap_{\alpha} H_{\alpha}$ is a Lie subgroup since it's a closed subgroup, but what about it's Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$? Is it always true to say that $\mathfrak{h}=\bigcap_{\alpha} \mathfrak{h_{\alpha}}$? ( $\mathfrak{h}\subset\bigcap_{\alpha} \mathfrak{h_{\alpha}}$ is easy, but what about the other direction?)If it's not true, any counterexample?

Comment: I think you can prove this by taking exponential map

Comment: Ben is right. The essential case is that of a single intersection (then induction handles finite intersections, and considerations with identity components and dimension handle the rest). For a literature reference, see Bourbaki, Lie groups and Lie Algebras, Ch. III, section 6, no. 2, Cor. 3 (which doesn't even require the $H_i$'s to be closed in $G$; enough for them to be "Lie subgroups" in the immersive sense going back to Chevalley).